Can multiple command arguments into variable and be expanded back in POSIX script?
In a POSIX shell script is it possible to store multiple command arguments into a variable and then expand that variable later in a command?
For example, given the following code that pass arguments to the find, it is possible to pass single-word arguments to the command:
rootname="$1"
case "$(uname)" in
    Darwin)
        mode='+111'
        ;;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

    Linux)
        mode='/111'
        ;;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
esac
if [ -n "$INCLUDE_SYMLINK" ]; then                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    find "${rootname}" -perm "${mode}" \( -type f -or -type l \)
else
    find "${rootname}" -perm "${mode}" -type f
fi


But is it possible to place a multiple words argument like the \( -type f -or -type l \) set of words into a variable and expand it back to do something like the following (which does not work because the quoting place everything inside 1 word):
if [ -n "$INCLUDE_SYMLINK" ]; then
    type_arg='\( -type f -or -type l \)'
else
    type_arg='-type f'
fi
find "${rootname}" -perm "${mode}" ${type_arg}


The backslashes are there to escape the parentheses from the shell (to the shell, parentheses launch the enclosed commands in a subshell)
If you're storing that phrase in a variable, omit the backslashes.
    type_arg='( -type f -or -type l )'

At this point, I would question why you are targeting POSIX shell. Are you deploying to platforms where bash is not available?

For bash, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 is relevant.

Yes, I am deploying in several systems that use various shell types and where a good version of Bash is not installed.
